# Handling multiple promises to get the total progress of multiple file downloads

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise, react-native-fs

I'm trying to download multiple files using [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) library and show the progress of the download to the user. For a single file download It can be use as the following code.

```
let fileSize = null;
let downloadedSize = null;
let progress = null;

RNFS.downloadFile({
  fromUrl: 'https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4',
  toFile: `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/download.mp4`,
  begin: ({jobId, contentLength}) => { fileSize = contentLength; },
  progress: ({jobId, bytesWritten, contentLength}) => {
    downloadedSize = bytesWritten;
    console.log("progress", downloadedSize / fileSize);
  },
});
```

For multiple file downloads I'm trying to use the same function with a *for of* loop. But was not able to get the progress correctly. The progress values are displayed like this

```
0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,50,60,70,80,90,80,90,100
```

The values are going back and forth. Following is the my code

```
const files = [
  'https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4',
  'https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_640_3MG.mp4',
  'https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_1280_10MG.mp4',
  'https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_1920_18MG.mp4',
];

const promises = [];
let jobs = [];
let index = 1;

for (const file of files) {
  const promise = RNFS.downloadFile({
    fromUrl: file,
    toFile: `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/download_${index}.mp4`,
    begin: ({ jobId, contentLength }) => {
      jobs.push({ jobId, contentLength, progress: 0 })
    },
    progress: ({ jobId, bytesWritten, contentLength }) => {
      jobs = jobs.map((job, index) => {
        if (jobId === job.jobId) {
          jobs[index].progress = bytesWritten;
        }
        return job;
      });
      const totalDownloadSize = jobs.reduce((total, current) => total + current.contentLength, 0);
      const currentDownloadSize = jobs.reduce((total, current) => total + current.progress, 0);
      console.log("progress", currentDownloadSize / totalDownloadSize);
    },
  });
  promises.push(promise);
  index++;
}
Promise.all(promises);
```

Is there anyway I can get the progress correctly?

Comment: When is `begin` called?

Comment: @JonasWilms begin is called before downloading the file. But when it comes to multiple files some files' progress function will call before another files' begin function

Comment: Then I'd pre initialize the array with some speculative large `contentLength`, and update it once begin is called.

Comment: Or alternatively calculate `percentage += (transmitted / size) / files.length` (which is a slightly different indication, though might he what you're looking for)

Comment: Aside: instead of `jobs[index]` you should just refer to `job` inside that `map` function. And you shouldn't actually use `map` if you don't plan to return different objects, use `for … of` loops to mutate objects in arrays.

Comment: Does `downloadFile` has builtin throttling?

Comment: @JonasWilms even though I do that (transmitted/size) will not be continuous right? It can go back & forth

Comment: @Bergi actually its a library function to download a single file. I didn't see it has built in throttling in the source code

Answer (score 2):

I would measure

```
(currentDownloadSize / totalDownloadSize) * (jobs.length / files.length)
```

to factor in the not-yet-started jobs.